# Bundle Products - how to use 2 different renderers for bundled product options? (to show in tab)

Tags: magento-1.9, tabs, bundle, option, renderer

I need two renderers for Bundle Product Select Style Options, to show the same thing differently in two places.

*Context: At the moment all my bundle products are fixed (wine cases). I have decided that I will use the "select" type for these, and customise the layout of them to fit this particular scenario. I am keeping everything else as is so that if I need other bundles in the future I can just use a different option type.
In the case of a fixed bundle, the whole list that appears in the product info block with the add to cart button is really clunky.*

*My idea was to clean it up:*

1. *change the bundle select.phtml block to not show product details in the product information block (leaving the hidden fields and javascript to submit to cart)*
2. *create a second, similar block, without any of the cart/javascript elements (to avoid conflicts), and put it in the description tabs*

I have managed to get 90% there purely with local.xml and design changes - but I am stuck on the select renderer. It is not using my second one `tabselect.phtml` where I want it to.

My local.xml (part) - i have basically reproduced what happens in catalog.xml and bundle.xml with new names and overriding the templates

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle translate="label" module="bundle">

<reference name="product.info">

<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.taboptions.wrapper" as="product_taboptions_wrapper" template="catalog/product/view/options/tabwrapper.phtml" translate="label">
    <label>Info Column Options Wrapper</label>
    <block type="bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle" name="product.info.bundle.options" as="type_bundle_options" template="catalog/product/view/options/taboptions.phtml">
        <action method="addRenderer"><type>select</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_select</block><template>bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/tabselect.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addRenderer"><type>multi</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_multi</block></action>
        <action method="addRenderer"><type>radio</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_radio</block></action>
        <action method="addRenderer"><type>checkbox</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_checkbox</block></action>
    </block>        
</block>

<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/options/bundletab.phtml">
    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Case Contents</value></action>
    <action method="append"><block>product.info.taboptions.wrapper</block></action>         
</block>

</reference>
```

My problem is the `<action method="addRenderer"><type>select</type><block>bundle/catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_select</block><template>bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/tabselect.phtml</template></action>` line

It is being happily ignored - see screenshot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeeKk.png)

QUESTIONS

1. **Is it something in my syntax?**

I am hoping I missed something in the syntax,

2. **Or Is this thing hard coded?**

I found this in the Core  `Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option_Select`

```
class Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option_Select
    extends Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option
{
    /**
     * Set template
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/select.phtml');
    }
}
```

Would this mean I cannot override the template no matter what?

If it is #2 it is I am left with three options:

- a module that creates an additional renderer - no idea how to do this!can you do just a renderer?
- a module that overrides this `Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option_Select` to allow for template change
- changing the main select.phtml renderer so it can be used in both
  cases - this would be ugly

[image: screenshot to illustrate]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with a separate module that creates a new renderer block.
you don't need anything fancy. If you want to keep the functionality of the select and just want to change the template, you can create the renderer block like this

```
<?php 
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option_Select 
extends Mage_Bundle_Block_Catalog_Product_View_Type_Bundle_Option_Select 
{
    pubic function _construct() 
    {
         parent::_construct();
         $this->setTemplate('bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/tabselect.phtml');
    }

}
```

then, in your layout file add this:

```
<reference name="product.info.taboptions.wrapper">
    <action method="addRenderer"><type>select</type><block>[block_alias_here]/catalog_product_view_type_bundle_option_select</block><template>bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle/option/tabselect.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

and make sure your module is marked as dependent on the `Mage_Bundle` module in the module declaration file in `app/etc/modules/`

Comment: That other template is truly hard coded, then?

Comment: it wasn't as painful as I feared. Just a few namespace blips

Comment: how to remove an existing rendered block? is there any method like "removeRender"?